# Deleting associated data from a pip package when uninstalling

Tags: python, caching, pip

I have a pip package that needs a ~5.5MB file to work properly. I've been told to avoid to put large files in git, so my pip package download it in the first run and install it on the folder `~/.cache/myprogram/`. How can I delete that folder when uninstalling that program with `pip uninstall myprogram`?

Comment: Can you manually delete it or just use cmd commands? https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/cmd-delete-folder-how-to-remove-files-and-folders-in-windows/

Comment: Yes I can, but I want to automate it to clean things after each uninstall.

Comment: @diksown What if admin/root/superuser installed the package system-wide (for all users) — should the uninstall remove the large file from all users? What if a user installed the package into 2 virtual environments — should the first uninstall remove the large file from the user leaving the second virtual environment unusable?

Comment: @phd, excellent question, I hadn't thought of that! Well, my program does something like `if not big_file_exists(), download_big_file_to_cache()` so it won't break things to anyone if the large file is deleted. I think there are two main problems for me: I don't want residues left if the user decides to uninstall the program, and if I update the program, the old file may be an outdated version, but my program wouldn't download a new version because it finds the file.

Comment: @diksown Alas, `pip` is not of big help here, it can only upgrade or uninstall `package_data` which you avoid. Everything else is up to the app.